# Issue in alertcondition pine script

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I have below pine script. it is executing Long condition when condition is met but it is also generating alert condition of sell condition even though condition is not met. can some one please help. The strange part is that i can see that sell signal is executed at tradetron but tradingview has not generated any alert. I tried by removing sellcondition then it is working fine.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Vwap-Long", shorttitle="Vwap-Long", overlay=true)
process_orders_on_close=true

//vwap caluclation
averageData = input.source(close, title="Average Data Source")
bandOffset = input.float(0.05, title="Price Band Offset (%)", step=0.05) / 100
vwapData = ta.vwap(averageData)
plot(vwapData, color=color.orange, title="VWAP")


// 13 EMA
ema_length = input.int(13, title="EMA Length")
ema = ta.ema(close, ema_length)
plot(ema, color=color.blue, title="13 EMA")

///////////////////////////////////////////VWAP-Long//////////////////////////////////////////////
var bool buy_condition_met_long = false

buy_condition_long =  ta.crossover(close, vwapData ) 
sell_condition_long = buy_condition_met_long and (ta.crossunder(close, ema) or ta.crossunder(close, vwapData))

alertcondition(buy_condition_long,title = "Long-Entry",message = "Entry-BuyFutureSellPE")

if (buy_condition_long)
    buy_condition_met_long := true

if (sell_condition_long)
    buy_condition_met_long := false

alertcondition(sell_condition_long,title = "Long-Exit",message = "Exit-BuyFutureSellPE")

plotshape(buy_condition_long ? 1 : na, title="Long-Entry", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, style=shape.triangleup,text="LEN")
plotshape(sell_condition_long ? 1 : na, title="Long-Exit", location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, style=shape.triangledown,text="LES")
```

Comment: Try adding `barstate.isconfirmed` to your conditions. As it is, it could repaint.

Answer (score 0):

if (buy_condition_long)
buy_condition_met_long := true

if (sell_condition_long)
buy_condition_met_long := false

Change above to

buy_condition_met_long:= nz(buy_condition_long?true:sell_condition_long?false:buy_condition_met_long[1],buy_condition_met_long[1])